# Sql select query dealing with multiple tables

Tags: php

I have table employees with columns: `id`, `employee_id` with values say `ABC1234` and `4` respectively.

Another table cashadvance with columns :`id`, `date_advance`, `employee_id`, `amount` with values say `3`, `2018-06-20`, `5`, `1500`.

Now i want do sql `select` query in PHP to show `date_advance` and `amount` for the specific user/logged in employee(username is `employee_id` e.g, `ABC1234` plus pswd) .

I have trouble cause `employee_id` in cashadvance is the primary key for `employee` in table employees. Please help

Comment: Always make the id column primary key of any table . Even creating foreign key is not a good approach .

Comment: Are you using a join and getting ambiguous error?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the query written for your purpose to get those data for employees in employees table and related data in cashadvance . Here an inner join is used , please run the query and let me know if you face any error .

```
$sql = "select *
        from employees as 'emp'
        inner join cashadvance as 'cad'
        on cad.employee_id = emp.employee_id
        where 1" ;
```

Comment: Don't use quotes for aliases. The `where 1` should be removed.

Comment: The SQL will be parsed from PHP to MySQL , so quotes are sometimes necessary . But where clause can be removed .

Comment: If they are needed they should be backticks because you are making it an identifier. If they are needed though one chose a bad identifier.

Comment: Used the code without the quotes, says no data available in table but thanks to artur klesun i was able to modify it as: $sql=“Select *,cashadvance.id as cad, employees.employee_id as emp from cashadvance inner join employees on employees.id=cashadvance.employee_id”; // now this code shows all the data from the table i.e,date and amount from all employees. I want to use ‘where’ to show only data for the current user but am having trouble. Have tried where employee_id =‘$user’”; to no avail. Will appreciate any help